# fast way to Join and filter data from multiple tables on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi first i'm sorry for my bad english...I develop a php application to input merchant visit result for my office.

Here the structure of my mysql database :

#### Table `merchant` :

```
id, name, address, phone, area
```

#### Table `device` :

```
id, merchid, tid, sn, status
```

#### Table `visit` :

```
id, date, time, merchid, deviceid, act, result
```

the relation for that 3 tables is below :

```
device.merchid -> merchant.id
visit.merchid -> merchant.id
visit.deviceid -> device.id
```

what i want is join that 3 tables as view that contain bellow field :

#### View `joindevice` :

```
devid, merchid, merchname, merchaddr, merchph, mercharea, devtid, devsn,
devstat, lastact, lastvisit, lastresult
```

where lastact, lastresult and lastvisit use data from 'visit' table for each device.
what i have done now is create mysql view using bellow query :

```
select
device.id AS devid,
device.merchid AS merchid,
merchant.name AS merchname,
merchant.address AS merchaddr,
merchant.phone AS merchph,
merchant.area AS mercharea,
device.tid AS devtid,
device.sn AS devsn,
device.status AS devstat,
ifnull(
(
select visit.act from visit
where visit.devid = device.id
order by visit.date desc limit 1
),''
)AS lastact,
ifnull(
(
select visit.date from visit
where (visit.devid=device.id)
order by visit.date desc limit 1
),''
)AS lastvisit,
ifnull(
(
select visit.result from visit
where (visit.devid=device.id)
order by visit.date desc limit1
),''
)AS lastresult
from (device join merchant) where (merchant.id=device.merchid)
```

here the php script to call that JoinDevice View :

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM joindevice order by merchname asc";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$check=mysql_num_rows($qry);
if($check>0){
?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>No.</th>
<th>TID</th>
<th>SN</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Merchant Name</th>
<th>Merchant Address</th>
<th>Merchant Area</th>
<th>Device Status</th>
<th>Last Visit</th>
<th>Last Act</th>
<th>Last Result</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$no=1;
while($dt=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['tid'])?'-':$dt['tid']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['sn'])?'-':$dt['sn']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['merchph'])?'-':$dt['merchph']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['merchname'])?'-':$dt['merchname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['merchaddr'])?'-':$dt['merchaddr']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['mercharea'])?'-':$dt['mercharea']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['devstat'])?'-':$dt['devstat']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['lastvisit'])?'-':$dt['lastvisit']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['lastact'])?'-':$dt['lastact']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo empty($dt['lastresult'])?'-':$dt['lastresult']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$no++;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

everything work fine when the data in 'device' table is small but now the data is about 1700 item so time to execute that php script is too long, sometime when i execute that php script the result is gateway timeout, but when i execute php script that only get data from one table it open fast...can anyone help me how to reduce that execute time?what should i do?

Comment: Is it compulsory for your use that every single row return at the same time? @anggazan

Answer (score 0):

You could try eliminating those correlated subqueries and replacing them with formal joins:

```
SELECT
    t1.id AS devid,
    t1.merchid AS merchid,
    t1.tid AS devtid,
    t1.sn AS devsn,
    t1.status AS devstat,
    t2.act AS lastact,
    t2.date AS lastvisit,
    t2.result AS lastresult,
    t3.name AS merchname,
    t3.address AS merchaddr,
    t3.phone AS merchph,
    t3.area AS mercharea,
FROM device t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM visit t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT devid, MAX(date) AS date
        FROM visit
        GROUP BY devid
    ) t2
        ON t1.devid = t2.devid AND
           t1.date  = t2.date
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.devid
INNER JOIN merchant t3
    t1.merchid = t3.id
```

Whether an index would prove beneficial to the above would depend on a number of things, but in any case I expect improvement over your original query.